# ¿Cómo guardar todos los print de un programa en un log si esta en segundo plano?

Tags: bash, shell

Me gustaría guardar todos los mensajes que muestra a través de **print** mi programa, en este caso `main.py`

Había probado con hacer lo siguiente en mi archivo `crearlog.sh`, y funciona cuando ejecuto en primer plano el proceso con `./crearlog.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
python main.py >> logextraccion.log
```

Pero cuando ejecuto en segundo plano con `./crearlog.sh &` no se guarda el texto en el log. ¿Por qué ocurre esto y cómo lo soluciono?

Añadir que no quiero modificar mi programa `main.py`, sino `crearlog.sh`.

El motivo por el cual quiero hacerlo en segundo plano es porque estoy con una conexión ssh a un servidor remoto.

Comment: supongo que esto sucede porque  `>>` redirecciona la salida estándar a un archivo, al no estar en primer plano la salida estándar no esta disponible o no es la esperada. No lo pongo como respuesta porque no estoy seguro.

Comment: también debes asegurarte que el programa este enviando datos a la salida estándar y no a la salida de error, en ese caso >> no te va a funcionar.

Comment: cambia la redireccion del stdout y stderr `python main.py > logextraccion.log 2>&1`

Comment: @JordiCastilla acabo de añadirlo pero siguen sin aparecer los textos en el log

Comment: uhm.... y `python main.py > logextraccion.log 2>&1 &` ejecutado como `.\crearlog.sh` ? sorry que no tengu un linux a mano para probar

Comment: Utiliza el paquete logger de Python, desde allí lo puedes direccionar a un archivo del sistema

Comment: intenta `main.py 2> logextraccion.log`

Comment: de la forma que indica @JordiCastilla debería funcionar.

Comment: He replicado el caso y me funciona incluso corriendolo en el background, otra cosa, los scripts no se llaman con `./script.sh` en vez de `.\script.sh`?

Comment: @CésarBustíos ups, error tipográfico mío, ahora editaré. En mi terminal lo escribo bien xD

Comment: @Elena xD, como te decía, a mi me funciona perfecto, tal vez el error este del lado de Python? No se me ocurre otra cosa

Comment: Ami también me funciona, tal vez no este dando error el python o no esté "logueando" lo que se espera.

Comment: @JordiCastilla  y Alan habíais acertado con python main.py > logextraccion.log 2>&1

Comment: @CésarBustíos sí, había un problema con el Python, pero con la solución que hablaban es correcto ya. Muchas gracias a todos :) Aunque agradecería una explicación más extensa, me he quedado con la incognita

Comment: @Elena excelente, es una cuestión de redireccionamiento de la salida estándar (sdtout) y del error estándar (stderr). Ni bien me desocupe agrego una respuesta explicando algunas cosas, pero me parece que la reputación le correspondería a JordiCastilla.  Me alegro que lo pudiste solucioanar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buenas, lo que deberías hacer es, además de redireccionar la salida estándar (stdout), redireccionar el error estándar (stderr).

Esto lo puedes hacer de varias maneras. Una forma es la que se indicó en los comentarios de la pregunta.

```
./tu_script.sh > logextraccion.log 2>&1 &
```

donde  `2>&1` le está diciendo a la salida de error estándar que vaya a la salida estándar (perdón por el trabalenguas) y el últmo `&` es porque lo quieres correr en background.

Una forma mas limpia es:

```
./tu_script.sh &> logextraccion.log &
```

Con `&>` le indicas que estas redireccionando ambas salidas.

Si quisieras podrías hacer lo inverso, enviar `stdout` a `stderr` (salida estándar a error estándar).

Esto lo haces así (lo pongo a modo de ejemplo ya que para tu caso no va):

```
./tu_script.sh > logextraccion.log 1>&2 &
```

En [este artículo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) (en inglés) puedes ver varias formas de redirección.

Answer (score 2):

En este caso es mejor utilizar `nohup` ya que entre otras cosas la ejecución continuará aunque hayas desconectado tu sesión.

```
nohup python main.py
```

Esto lanzará el programa en segundo plano y toda la salida quedará almacenada en `nohup.out`

Para verificar si el programa esta corriendo puedes usar

```
jobs -l
```

#### Más información acerca de [`nohup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

Comment: Esto es muy interesante, no lo conocía. Investigaré más ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo si trabajas con conexiones via ssh a servidores remotos, aparte de la solución aportada, es que te familiarices con el programa **screen** (o *byobu*), éste te permitirá desconectarte y reconectarte manteniendo tu sesión de usuario y pudiendo retomar las cosas donde las dejaste, sobre todo con procesos que duran mucho y que una caída de la conexión puede hacer que el proceso se caiga también a la vez que tu sesión.

El uso básico es muy sencillo:

```
$ screen
```

Te lanzará una sesión nueva, ahí puedes lanzar tu script.
Pulsas "Ctrl + a d", te desconectas de esas sesión y puedes cerrar la conexión ssh, para reconectarte posteriormente, accedes via ssh y solo tienes que escribir:

```
$ screen -r
```

y voila.

Nota: Puedes abrir tantas sesiones screen como quieras, luego con -r te pedirá que especifiques la que quieras.